# bash equivalent of 'set -x' in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

In bash, running:

```
$ set -x
$ rm *
+ rm foo bar
```

whereas in zsh `set -x` does not do the same thing. In short `set -x` in bash allows you to see what you are really doing in the shell. I run zsh on my local. Is there a command to do the same?

I should add that the issue in zsh is that it sends like 30 or so lines of output that I don't want or need. I just want to know what the shell did to my command.

Comment: `zsh -x -c 'echo "foo"'`?

Comment: `set -x` should do the same thing in zsh that it does in bash. What does it do when you try it?

Comment: like 30 or so lines of information starting with : `+update_terminal_cwd:some_integer>` @GordonDavisson

Comment: same issue as above @Cyrus

Comment: @user18348324 That *is* doing the same thing as in bash, but you have a bunch of stuff being auto-run between every command you enter; see my answer to ["Why does 'set -x' cause the terminal to dump garbage"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238736/why-does-set-x-cause-the-terminal-to-dump-garbage) (which is about this happening in bash). I think you can disable the auto-run stuff in zsh with `precmd_functions=()`

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to `set -x` in zsh is `setopt xtrace`

```bash
$ setopt xtrace
$ rm *
rm foo bar
$ unsetopt xtrace
```

To turn off the display use `unsetopt xtrace`

You can also use the `PS4` prompt to customize the output. E.g. to show the line number

```bash
$ PS4='+%L: '
$ setopt xtrace
$ rm *
+7: rm foo bar
```

Comment: still shows lots of lines of output instead of just the one

Answer (score 0):

From the zsh's `man zshoptions`:

```
XTRACE (-x, ksh: -x)
              Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.  The output is preceded by the value of $PS4, formatted as described in the section EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES in zshmisc(1).
```

In practice:

```
#!/bin/zsh -x

echo "foo"
```

---

```
$> ./test.sh                                                                                                                                                                                        ✔  1954  15:10:23
+./test.sh:3> echo foo
foo
```

Comment: how would this command look in the shell? if it is simply `zsh -x`, it sends me lots of lines of output I don't need